# How to find and replace the value array item if condtion is true

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I have an array like below

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: "first",
    val: 'ganguly',
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    val: 'sachin',
  },
 ]
 
 const selectedVaue ='dhoni';
```

if id is match to 'third' then value to replace to particular key

```
const list = arr.filter(data => data.id === 'third');
     if (list.length > 0 ) {
         // code 
     }
```

Expected result lie below :

```
    const arr = [
  {
    id: "first",
    val: 'ganguly',
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    val: 'dhoni',
  },
 ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; it seems like this would require iterating the list, checking the `id` property, and setting `val` if there's a match. A `filter` seems unnecessary; this should almost certainly be done with a single iteration if you're destructively modifying the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create a new array with the value with `id` `"third"` replaced.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "first", val: "ganguly" },
  { id: "third", val: "sachin" },
];

const selectedValue = "dhoni";

const res = arr.map((a) =>
  a.id === "third" ? { ...a, val: selectedValue } : a
);

console.log(res);
```

Or you can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you want to replace the object in place.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "first", val: "ganguly" },
  { id: "third", val: "sachin" },
];

const selectedValue = "dhoni";

arr.forEach((a, i) => {
  if (a.id === "third") {
    arr[i] = { ...a, val: selectedValue };
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```